# Flutter StreamBuilder not working after Page Reload

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, stream-builder

I have a Registration page with TextField Form Validators in my App with a button. The text field will display form validation error messages if business rules haven't been met and the "next" button will be tap-able once all criteria has been met. This is currently all working well in my app but I find that once I leave the page and return to it, the validation error messages stops displaying and the button stops working as well. Looking at the console logs in my IDE (android studio) the only relevant error message I am getting is

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: 
Stream is already closed
#0      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add 
(dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:66:7)
#1      _EventSinkWrapper.add 
(dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)
```

I'm not exactly sure what this means, does the stream close and not reopen once the page has been reloaded? If not, is there a way i could fix this or is there something i'm missing?  [This is](https://ibb.co/vsLTqWc) what i'm experiencing

Stream Builder Code:

```
    Widget emailField(authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: authBloc.emailStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          onChanged: authBloc.updateEmail,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange
                )
              ),
              hintText: 'Enter Email',
              labelText: 'Email Address',
              errorText: snapshot.error
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget passwordField( authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: authBloc.passwordStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          onChanged: authBloc.updatePassword,
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Enter password',
            labelText: 'Password',
            errorText: snapshot.error,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }


  Widget checkPasswordField( authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: authBloc.validatePasswordStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          onChanged: authBloc.updateValidatePassword,
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Re-enter password',
            labelText: 'Confirm Password',
            errorText: snapshot.error,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget nextBtn(authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: authBloc.submitValid,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          return RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Next'),
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0))
            ),
            onPressed: snapshot.hasData
                ? () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register')
            : null,
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

Streams:

```
       /// REGISTER VARIABLES
  static final _emailController = BehaviorSubject<
      String>(); //RxDart's implementation of StreamController. Broadcast stream by default
  static final _passwordController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  static final _validatePasswordController = BehaviorSubject<
      String>(); // Will check that the password entered the 2nd time is correct

 /// REGISTER STREAM & METHODS
  //Retrieve data from the stream
  Stream<String> get emailStream => _emailController.stream
      .transform(performEmailValidation); //Return the transformed stream

  Stream<String> get passwordStream =>
      _passwordController.stream.transform(performPasswordValidation);

  Stream<String> get validatePasswordStream =>
      _validatePasswordController.stream.transform(performIsPasswordSame);

 //Merging email, password and validate password
  Stream<bool> get submitValid => Observable.combineLatest3(
      emailStream, passwordStream, validatePasswordStream, (e, p1, p2) => true);

//Add data to the stream
  Function(String) get updateEmail => _emailController.sink.add;
  Function(String) get updatePassword => _passwordController.sink.add;
  Function(String) get updateValidatePassword =>
      _validatePasswordController.sink.add;

// performing user input validations
  final performEmailValidation = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (email, sink) async {
    String emailValidationRule =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(emailValidationRule);
    if (await doesNameAlreadyExist("email", _emailController.value) == true)
      sink.addError("That email already exists");
    else if (regExp.hasMatch(email)) {
      sink.add(email);
    } else {
      sink.addError(StringConstant.emailErrorMessage);
    }
  });

  final performPasswordValidation =
      StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
          handleData: (_passwordController, sink) {
    if (_passwordController.length >= 6) {
      sink.add(_passwordController);
    } else {
      sink.addError(StringConstant.passwordErrorMessage);
    }
  });

  final performIsPasswordSame = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (password, sink) {
    if (password != _passwordController.value)
      sink.addError(StringConstant.invalidPasswordMessage);
    else
      sink.add(password);
  });
```

Entire Screen Code:

```
class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}



class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  AuthBloc _authBloc;



  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _authBloc = AuthBlocProvider.of(context);
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(

      body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 80,),
                Text("Register", style: Style.appTextStyle),
                SizedBox(height: 100,),
                emailField(_authBloc),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                passwordField(_authBloc),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                checkPasswordField(_authBloc),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    cancelBtn(),

                    nextBtn(_authBloc),

                  ],
                )

                // checkPasswordField(authBloc),
              ],
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget emailField(authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: authBloc.emailStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          onChanged: authBloc.updateEmail,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange
                )
              ),
              hintText: 'Enter Email',
              labelText: 'Email Address',
              errorText: snapshot.error
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget passwordField( authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: authBloc.passwordStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          onChanged: authBloc.updatePassword,
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Enter password',
            labelText: 'Password',
            errorText: snapshot.error,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }


  Widget checkPasswordField( authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: authBloc.validatePasswordStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          onChanged: authBloc.updateValidatePassword,
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Re-enter password',
            labelText: 'Confirm Password',
            errorText: snapshot.error,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget nextBtn(authBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: authBloc.submitValid,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          return RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Next'),
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0))
            ),
            onPressed: snapshot.hasData
                ? () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register')
            : null,
          );
        }
    );
  }

  Widget cancelBtn(){
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Cancel'),
      color: Colors.white30,
      shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0))
      ),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _authBloc.dispose();
  }
```

Bloc Code:

```
/// REGISTER VARIABLES
      static final _emailController = BehaviorSubject<
          String>(); //RxDart's implementation of StreamController. Broadcast stream by default
      static final _passwordController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
      static final _validatePasswordController = BehaviorSubject<
          String>(); // Will check that the password entered the 2nd time is correct

     /// REGISTER STREAM & METHODS
      //Retrieve data from the stream
      Stream<String> get emailStream => _emailController.stream
          .transform(performEmailValidation); //Return the transformed stream

      Stream<String> get passwordStream =>
          _passwordController.stream.transform(performPasswordValidation);

      Stream<String> get validatePasswordStream =>
          _validatePasswordController.stream.transform(performIsPasswordSame);

     //Merging email, password and validate password
      Stream<bool> get submitValid => Observable.combineLatest3(
          emailStream, passwordStream, validatePasswordStream, (e, p1, p2) => true);

    //Add data to the stream
      Function(String) get updateEmail => _emailController.sink.add;
      Function(String) get updatePassword => _passwordController.sink.add;
      Function(String) get updateValidatePassword =>
          _validatePasswordController.sink.add;

    // performing user input validations
      final performEmailValidation = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
          handleData: (email, sink) async {
        String emailValidationRule =
            r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
        RegExp regExp = new RegExp(emailValidationRule);
        if (await doesNameAlreadyExist("email", _emailController.value) == true)
          sink.addError("That email already exists");
        else if (regExp.hasMatch(email)) {
          sink.add(email);
        } else {
          sink.addError(StringConstant.emailErrorMessage);
        }
      });

      final performPasswordValidation =
          StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
              handleData: (_passwordController, sink) {
        if (_passwordController.length >= 6) {
          sink.add(_passwordController);
        } else {
          sink.addError(StringConstant.passwordErrorMessage);
        }
      });

      final performIsPasswordSame = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
          handleData: (password, sink) {
        if (password != _passwordController.value)
          sink.addError(StringConstant.invalidPasswordMessage);
        else
          sink.add(password);
      });

    dispose() {
        _emailController.close();
        _passwordController.close();
        _validatePasswordController.close();

    }
```

Comment: I need see where and how you're creating and disposing your BLoC instance. Please share if possible the entire screen code and BLoC too. But as the message error says "*Stream is already closed*" means that you're closing BLoC streams probably when you go the next route and when you back to your "FORM SCREEN" you're using the same BLoC instance but with all streams already closed. Are you using InheritedWidget to get Bloc?

Comment: I updated my question with the code where i'm initializing and closing bloc instance. How do i use another BLoC instance once user has left and returned back to the page? and yes I am using the inheritedWidget to get Bloc

Comment: You should use the same BLoC instance as you already doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, looking to full source and the GIF that you show I can see what is causing this problem.
Your mistake is call `dispose()` BLoC instance method in `dispose()` SingUp widget class method.

Why is a mistake?

In your specific case when you're in SingUp screen and go to a next route/screen `dispose` method from SingUp is called and in this moment the streams of your BLoC instance is going to be closed. But the next allows the user go back to SingUp screen and when this happen SingUp instance gets the same BLoC instance that was used before but this BLoC instance has the streams already closed.

How can I solve this in a simple way?

In SingUp class :

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
   /// DON'T CALL BLoC dispose here
   /// _authBloc.dispose();
  }
```

Don't dispose you BloC here because the user can back to this screen any moment. Since you're using InheritedWidget to get BLoC instance and this gives you access the same BLoC instance in different places I advise you call `yourBloc.dispose()` in the moment where the user is ending all the sing up process.

Comment: ohh thanks for the clear explanation. How would i go about initializing another instance of the bloc assuming the user cancels registration by accident and decides to go back

Comment: To do this you don't need InheritedWidget to create you BLoC. You just need create a BLoC instance using YouBlocConstructor inside your SingUp class and make this bloc instance as member of SingUp state class. But be aware that when user go back to SingUp screen for some reason, create and using a new Bloc instance can makes you loose the previous user data.